# How to solve this differential equation involving an integral

Tags: calculus, integro-differential-equations

I am working on a problem involving finding a function for which the area under the curve is equal to the arc length. I therefore come up with $\int_a^b(k\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]²} -f(x))dx =0$. Frankly, I have no idea where to even start to solve this. I have read that it may involve hyperbolic functions, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: This looks more like a calculus of variations problem than differential equations.

Comment: Is this an identity in $a$ and $b$ ?  Also, what can you tell us about $k$, from the description it looks like $k=1$.

Comment: k is a real constant, and so are a and b.